# Android : Get the list of images to download added in the separate folder of Firebase console from a FireBase Storage API

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-storage

I have an list of images with separate folder that is directly uploaded in the Fire-base console. I want to download that images into the app to display it in the grid using an storage API.

I looked into this https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files
but this is only for the single image to download and have to specified an name for that.

Basically I want to get all the images with multiple categories that is stored in the separate folder in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to download a image from Firebase Storage, you first need to have the corresponding url of the image. To download a image, it requires more steps:

> 1. Upload the image to Firebase Storage.
> 2. Save the corresponding url to Firebase Database while uploading.
> 3. Attach a listener on the folder you have saved the image.
> 4. Display the image.

Let's say your Firebase Storage structure looks something like this:

```
Storage-root
   |
   --- Photos
         |
         --- FolderNo1
         |      |
         |      --- image1.jpg
         |      |
         |      --- image2.jpg
         |
         --- FolderNo2
                |
                --- image3.jpg
                |
                --- image3.jpg
```

The coresponding database structure of your Firebase database that stores the urls of the images should look like this:

```
Firebase-root
   |
   --- Photos
         |
         --- FolderNo1
         |      |
         |      --- imageName1: imageUrl1
         |      |
         |      --- imageName2: imageUrl2
         |
         --- FolderNo2
                |
                --- imageName3: imageUrl3
                |
                --- imageName4: imageUrl4
```

The folder names in the Firebase database can be simple names (but be sure when uploading to check the names for uniqueness) or can be random unique ids, in which case i recomand you using the `push()` method.

If you are saving the images through Firebase Console, you cannot get the image url, that's why you should do this programmatically.

Firestore documentation shows how to download just a single image because even if you download a single image or more images, the code is almost the same.

If you want to get all urls from a single folder, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference folderRef = rootRef.child("Photos").child("FolderNo1");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String imageName = ds.getKey();
            String imageUrl = ds.getValue(String.class);
            list.add(imageUrl);
        }
        Log.d("TAG", list);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
folderRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

If you want to get all urls from all folders, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference photosRef = rootRef.child("Photos");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String imageName = ds.getKey();
            String imageUrl = ds.getValue(String.class);
            list.add(imageUrl);
        }
        Log.d("TAG", list);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
photosRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

In both cases, as you probably see, you get a `List` of urls. Having this list, you can now download the desired images according to [Firebase Storage Office Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files) but instead of using one url as mentioned there, you need to use a `List` of urls.

Comment: Not able to find this class DatabaseReference  and ValueEventListener. As per the documentation StorageReference. Can you please let me know is their anything I am missing or your above mentioned code is not the updated one.

Comment: I added compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.0.1' in build.gradle this and its working.

Comment: So have you solved the problem? Is there everything alright?

Comment: Yes..Solved the problem. But it seems like we have to do it via using StorageReference as this is the latest as per the document. Can you please let me know is that above implementation is as per the latest doc.

Comment: `StorageReference` is needed when uploading image. The code above is for reading the urs from the Firebase database and yes, it is per the latest doc. Did my answer helped you?

Answer (score 0):

you need to save path and image name in realtime database at upload images time in firebase database than you will get all images

showing in below image

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]